# std::map::find does not access operator==

Tags: c++, stl

I created a class MyString and overloaded operator==.
MyString can be used without any problems

```
class MyString
{
public:
    bool operator== (const MyString& obj) const;
};
```

I want to use MyString as key in std::map.

```
std::map<MyString, value> m_xxx;
```

I can access the inserted data by iterating.

```
for (auto& it : m_ini)
{
    MyString first = it.first;
    for (auto& sit : it.second)
    {
        MyString key = sit.first;
        MyString value = sit.second; 
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

But when using std::map::find the data I inserted cannot be searched

```
auto& it = m_ini.find(section);
if (it == m_ini.end())
```

I take for granted that std::map::find will do the comparison through my operator==.But in VS debugger std::map::find single step doesn't break down at my operator== .
I don't know where the problem is, can anyone help me!

Comment: `std::map` requires `bool operator<`.

Comment: Yes, operator< comes in. grateful@273K Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::map` does not use `operator==`. It is a sorted container and by default `operator<` is used to compare keys of elements in the map.

[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) has 4 template arguments:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map
```

The third one can be used to select a different comparator. `std::less<Key>` uses the keys `operator<`.

Actually a `std::map` does not care about equality. Two keys `a` and `b` are considered *equivalent* when `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`. Keys are not required to have an `operator==`.

Comment: Thanks, my MyString still needs a lot of work.

Comment: "*Two keys `a` and `b` are considered equivalent when `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`*" - well, more accurately, when `!Compare(a,b) && !Compare(b,a)`, so the `Compare` can be customized but is `std::less` by default.